# Angularjs ng-click doesn't work inside scope (Firefox only)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I just play around with angularjs and its functions. I simply try to click a button and return a string in `console.log`. When I click the button, nothing happens even no error message is visible. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HJ1emxXdZynDas9tMqo7?p=preview)

Update: In Chrome developer console it works, in Firefox console not!

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app='MyApp' ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
      {{name}}<br />
      <button ng-click="executeCmd()">Click Me</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

## script.js

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.name = 'Hello World';
      $scope.executeCmd = function () {
        console.log('print my Command');
      }
    });
```

Comment: show the code of the function also the markup, how you managed to get 56 rep points????

Comment: It works for me

Comment: okay i update my answer, else there is a link to plunker  if you havent see it ^^

Comment: So in chrome that works for as well but, not in firefox. Are these common problems or maybe i made a syntax failure!?

Comment: Mansuro: did you test this in firefox?

Comment: working in firefox too!!

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQBrOJ?editors=1011 - This works perfectly in Firefox 48

Comment: Okay now i got it. It as my fault. thanks for helping me guys!